# NaN error and number staying the same

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to re-write plug.dj for my mc server & friends, but I need help wit this code. I am new to stackoverflow, so forgive some errors.

CODE:

```
function voteYes() {
 var yes;
 yes = yes + 1
 window.alert(yes);
}
```

When the window pops up, it displays "1" always, without adding 1 and sometimes only displaying "NaN" ( I know it means Not a Number ). I want to add a vote system. So if "yes" exceeds 1 or 2 it switches video. Thanks!

Comment: It's just not possible that the code you've shown sometimes displays anything other than NaN. Could you show your actual code please?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var yes =0;
function voteYes() {
 //var yes;
 yes = yes + 1
 window.alert(yes);
}
```

I can't add a comment so my suggestion is that you should initialize yes before using it 
i.e.

> var yes = 0;  yes = yes+1 ;

and then do whatever you want to do